# sending plain text with space from an EditText to a mysql db?

Tags: android, phpmyadmin

Please i am trying to send from an `EditText` a text with space between words but nothing inserted in my db !

and when i send a text with no space works and inserted !

please what is the problem here ??

```
MyAsyncTaskresources attemptLogin= new MyAsyncTaskresources();
attemptLogin.execute("http://xxx.xxxxx.com/add_demande.php?de="+infos_demande.getStringExtra("de").toString()+"&a="+infos_demande.getStringExtra("a").toString()+"&date="+infos_demande.getStringExtra("date").toString()+"&heur="+infos_demande.getStringExtra("heur").toString()+"&id_user="+infos_demande.getStringExtra("id_conducteur"+i).toString());
```

Comment: In order to give a correct answer make sure you also post the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Encode the String values using `URLEncoder.encode(<Query Value>,"UTF-8")` before appending the values to the URL String.

```
MyAsyncTaskresources attemptLogin= new MyAsyncTaskresources();                 
attemptLogin.execute("http://xxx.xxxxx.com/add_demande.php?de="+URLEncoder.encode(infos_demande.getStringExtra("de").toString(),"UTF-8")+"&a="+URLENcoder.encode(infos_demande.getStringExtra("a").toString(),"UTF-8")+"&date="+URLEncoder.encode(infos_demande.getStringExtra("date").toString(),"UTF-8")+"&heur="+URLEncoder.encode(infos_demande.getStringExtra("heur").toString(),"UTF-8")+"&id_user="+URLEncoder.encode(infos_demande.getStringExtra("id_conducteur"+i).toString(),"UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try adding

```
 N'
```

as a first part of the string?

Answer (score 0):

First make your code readable, build your string before putting it in `attemptLogin.execute(...)`

now you have your string build you can check your string, try that and make sure your attemptLogin.execute() argument is a legit string!

Answer (score 0):

using volley is best and fast than use this old process

[volley library in android](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) , can send request and get response easy and adding parameter such as string and no problem of space , and there is handle for server error to check where your error

Comment: welcome , and if you have any question on volley ask me and i will help you as possible as i can